# vb6: click button on HTMLDocument by code and wait for page to be loaded

Tags: vb6, mshtml, readystate

i'm using the mshtml.tlb for loading/parsing html and i'd like extend it for clicking elements by code. the problem is trapping the loading-process after eg. a button was clicked.
in my specific case i'd like to perform a user-login.

here's my code:

```
Dim WithEvents m_doc As HTMLDocument

' load page
Set m_docNU = New HTMLDocument
Set m_doc = m_docNU.createDocumentFromUrl(m_url, vbNullString)

Do While m_doc.readyState = "loading" Or m_doc.readyState = "interactive"
DoEvents
Loop

set txtUsername = m_doc.getElementById("username")
set txtPasswort = m_doc.getElementById("passwort")
set myButton = m_doc.getElementById("submit")

myButton.click
```

now here's the big question mark: how to continue vb6- like "wait until page is loaded"?
i've tried as above using a do while-loop and checking the readyState, but for some reason the readyState doesn't change after clicking the button ..

any ideas?

thanks

ps: is there a more elegant way instead of the do while-loop? eg. using a progressbar?

Answer (score 0):

- use vb.net
- wBrowser is a webbroser object

  ```
  While wBrowser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
       Application.DoEvents()
  End While
  ```